# Unity-Android _ CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, ads, startapp

i'm using Windows 7, jdk 1.8.0 (64bit), jre 8 (64bit), Unity Pro 4.3.4f1 and Android SDK 22.6.1

All are updated softwares.
All works fine but when i use **StartApp** sdk, this error comes. No extra plugin is used, only the SDK provided by the StartApp ad.

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:/android-sdks\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/unity3d/player/a$1;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
1 error; aborting
]
```

I already tried JAVA_OPT and JAVA_HOME solutions. But still couldn't solved

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this using IntelliJ 13.1.4, JDK 1.6 but I would guess that this is caused by the same thing on any other IDE ->  classes.jar is referenced/included more than once.

Check and make sure that the classes.jar you added to the project (from Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar) isn't referenced/included more than once.  If you go into File->Project Structure:
There should only be one "classes" under libraries.
There should be NO reference to classes under Artifacts (Artifacts is used to create the plugin .jar file.)

Check out this related answer ->
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437996/3464367

Answer (score 0):

My issue was actually related to having duplicate files. Well not really duplicates, but I had 2 adMob sdk packages (different versions), that were getting into conflict. After deleting the older one, everything was fixed. Are you using any 3rd party SDK's or something similar, if so, try removing them if possible and see if the issue persists. Try to find out which part of the code is causing this to happen. You could ultimately try to compile an empty project just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Today I solved similar problem of *Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.* with adding .jar file into Plugins\Android\

I got different kind of errors:

1. Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000 ...
2. Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (ht/stringing/test) does not match path (src/ht/stringing/test.class)

My result working solution was similar to [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/creating-a-jar-for-an-android-plugin.115426/):

Code lives here:

```
verysimple\src\ht\stringing\test.java
```

I do:

```
> javac -classpath "c:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-15" ht\stringing\test.java
> jar cvf ..\dist\verysimple.jar ht\stringing\test.class
> copy  ..\dist\verysimple.jar c:\ExUnityApp\Assets\Plugins\Android
```

Don't forget to compare your 'Minimum Api Level' in Player Setting. For me it was **Android 4.0.3 ... (15)**