# Error when trying to integrating OneSignal to Xamarin.Forms Android app

Tags: android, jar, xamarin.forms, google-play-services, onesignal

The guide for integrating OneSignal with a Xamarin.Forms app seams really straight forward. But... After finishing all the setups, I got this error when trying to build my Android project:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlv; (MyProject.Droid)
```

I have already found similar issues:

- [Android Build fail - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/api/client/escape/CharEscapers;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437796/android-build-fail-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-already-added-lcom-goo)
- ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

But I do not know how to apply the solutions to a Xamarin.Forms Android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `already added :  Lcom/google/android/gms/internal` error means you have 2 copies of the Google Play services library in your project.
The OneSignal SDK already includes the Google Play services dependencies.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Com.OneSignal/

Check that you don't have your own copy under `Components` or `Packages` in your solution.